# Imagem em javascript

Tags: javascript

Preciso que o usuário escreva uma senha certa e com isso apareça uma imagem

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>SENHA</title>
    </head>
</html>

<script>
    var senha = ('teste')
    var escrita = (window.prompt('SENHA'))

    if(senha == escrita){
        document.write("S")
    }else{
        document.write("N")
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Boa parte do código que você disponibilizou estava correto.
Somente o que faltou foi você imprimir o objeto da imagem dentro do seu `HTML` desta forma abaixo.

```js
let senha = "teste";
let escrita = window.prompt("SENHA");

if(senha === escrita){
   document.write(`<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x90.png?text=ACERTOU!">`);
}else{
   document.write(`<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x90.png?text=ERROU!">`);
}
```

você também pode incluir utilizando jquery desta forma:

```
 let senha = "teste";
    let escrita = window.prompt("SENHA");
    
    if(senha === escrita){
       $("#seuobjetopodeserumadiv").html(`<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x90.png?text=ACERTOU!">`);
    }else{
       $("#seuobjetopodeserumadiv").html(`<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x90.png?text=ERROU!">`);
    }
```

Comment: vdd vc tem razao.

Answer (score -3):

Acho que você quer algo tipo isso.

```js
imgacertou = document.getElementById('Acertou')
senha = document.getElementById('senha')
confirmabtn = document.getElementById('Confirma')
TextoDaTela = document.getElementById('PedirSenha')

confirmabtn.addEventListener('click', function() {

if(senha.value == 'SenhaCorreta'){
   senha.value = '' //Limpar a area de texto
  
   confirmabtn.style.display = 'none'
   senha.style.display = 'none'
   TextoDaTela.style.display = 'none'
   
   imgacertou.style.display = 'block'

  }



})
```

```css
#Acertou{
display: none;
width: 100px;
heigh: 100px;
}

#PedirSenha {
display: block
}

#senha {
display: inline-flex;
}

#Confirma {
display: inline-flex;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>


<img id='Acertou' src='https://gartic.com.br/imgs/mural/of/ofantasmazul/acertar.png'>

<h1 id='PedirSenha'>Digite a senha</h1>

<input id='senha' type='password' required></input>
<button id='Confirma'>Confirmar</button>

</body>
</html>
```